# add slope and r^2 in a graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code

```
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
x1 = delta_ST_all.iloc[0:47,15].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y1 = delta_ST_all.iloc[0:47,1].values.reshape(-1, 1)  
linear_regressor = LinearRegression()
linear_regressor.fit(x1, y1) 
y1_pred = linear_regressor.predict(x1)
plt.scatter(x1, y1, label='AE 220-225m', s=20, color='lightpink')
plt.plot(x1, y1_pred, color='lightpink')
```

but I want to add a legend with the slope and r^2, can someone please help me with that?
I have been able to print it and see it but I can't find the code to put it in a legend on the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `plt.text`:

```
plt.text(0.8,0.9,
        'Slope={:.2g}\nR²{:.2g}'.format(float(slope),float(r2)),
        fontsize=16,ha='center')
```

where `slope`, `r2` are the values that you calculated

Then the text with be placed at position x=0.8, y=0.9, where x and y are values of your data. 
If you want to place the text in the relative position x, y to axes (which is a unit square),then:

```
ax=plt.gca()
plt.text(0.8,0.9,
        'Slope={:.2g}\nR²{:.2g}'.format(float(slope),float(r2)),
        transform =ax.transAxes,fontsize=16,ha='center')
```

Here the text will go the the top right corner where x=0.8, y=0.9, relative to the axes.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, just instead of putting plt we have to put ax and define it by using ax = plt.gca()

Comment: I edited the answer giving comparison cases between with or without ax=plt.gca. If you think it is helpful, could you upvote or accept it as answer?

Comment: I approved it and thank you, I wanted to ask another question, what if you have nan values in the list? I am getting this error ext(0.3, 0.1, 'Slope=nan\nR²=nan')